# Unable to get data from string in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to get the 'id' of LinkedIn profiles using Python.
By ID, I mean from `https://www.linkedin.com/in/adigup21/`, it should get adigup21.
I am using this trick `ID = (link.lstrip("https://www.linkedin.com/in/").rstrip('/'))`
But for some cases, it misses out on characters or is blank (I always make sure the format is same and good)

Is there any accurate alternative present for this?

Comment: you can use `rsplit()` like this `s.rstrip('/').rsplit('/', 1)[-1]`

Comment: how about ```ID = (link.lstrip("https://www.linkedin.com/in/").rsplit('/'))[0]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link.rstrip('/').split('/').pop()`

rstrip removes the (optional) final slash, split makes an array out of the slash-separated parts, pop extracts the last element.

BTW, this is just a hack. Manipulating URLs elements is best done with URL parsing, along the lines of

`pth=urllib.parse.urlparse(link).path`

One can then do rstrip/split/pop thing on pth.

Comment: add some explanation don't  post code only answers